# supervised machine learning: relationship between number of data points and variables

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

Let say. We have a dataset (in .csv format) for supervised machine learning. It has 60 data points (row of data), and each data point has 100 variables.

Does it make sense that I train machine learning models using all 100 variables from 60 data points? To me, it seems that it is mathematically wrong. It like I solve an equation set that with 100 variables, but only 60 equations?

In a dataset, if we have n variables, what is the minimal number of data points we need to train a machine learning model?

Any statistic theory for this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, you are right, it does not make sense to try to generalize a model with 100 features but only 60 examples.

The statistical reason has been widely explained in "statistical learning theory" by Vladimir Vapnik. I do not really suggest going and read all that book, it is a large book and lots of math, and not too many examples. But the point that you need to know is what is called [Vapnik Chervonenkis dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_dimension) or most of the time, it is being called **VC dimension**.

But long story short, in cases where the dimension is bigger than the number of training examples, what you will get is not a generalization, but an overfitting

Comment: Thank you very much. It is really helpful.